# Cant escape PHP code in mustache variables

Tags: php, json, mustache, mustache.php, patternlab.io

I'm using the PHP version of mustache, and also patternLab - which I think also uses the PHP version of mustache.

**example 1 : PHP version of mustache**
*I've also tried using the escape option, to no avail*
*Using triple {{{}}} doesn't work either*

```
<?php
$test = "meow";
$meow = '<?php echo $test?>';

$mm = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'escape' => function($text) { return $text; }
));

echo $mm->render('Hello, {{cat}}!', array('cat' => $meow)); // "Hello, meow!"
?>
```

this will render:

```
<!--?php echo $test?-->
```

**example patternlab:**

JSON file

```
{
    "echotest" : "<?php echo $test; ?>"
}
```

mustache file

```
<h2>{{{echotest}}}</h2>
```

outputs:

```
<h2><!--?php echo $test; ?--></h2>
```

Both times, the code is commented out, and not actually rendered. This is not what I want ;)

Maybe I'm going about this in the entirely wrong way, but I would like to have PHP in my mustache files, so that code can be used later on in my process, when I require these mustache files in a PHP project.

Comment: Are you trying to output the PHP as text, or execute the PHP inside a PHP variable?  Either way, you shouldn't be doing it.  Your internal code should never be output to the end user, and you can't execute PHP inside of a string like that.

Comment: In this context just outputting text.

I did eventually figure out that it was MUCH better to bind PHP values to mustaches variables, and pass in strings, rather than passing PHP code.